# Thumbor focal() filter not taken into account

Tags: image-processing, image-resizing, thumbor

I'm trying to replicate the example of the [focal()](https://thumbor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/focal.html?highlight=focal) docs.

When going to the URL:

```
http://localhost:8888/unsafe/400x100/filters:focal(146x206:279x360)/https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fthumbor%2Fthumbor%2Fraw%2Fmaster%2Fexample.jpg
```

I'm supposed to get this picture as a result:

[image]

But I'm getting instead:

[image]

Which is the same as if I removed the `/filters:focal(146x206:279x360)` part, so it looks like it's simply ignored.

**What am I doing wrong?** I'm using Thumbor `6.4.2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed to be an issue with this particular Thumbor version.

**Upgrading to `6.7.0` fixed the problem.**